# How can I move the cursor quickly to a specific location in a text I have just copy pasted in an Advanced Scripting command?

Tags: naturallyspeaking

I am writing an Advanced Scripting voice command in Dragon NaturallySpeaking Professional 11.5 to write SQL commands by voice. Regarding the `ORDER BY variable_name ASC` command, I would like to move cursor right before ASC:

```
Sub Main
    Clipboard(" ORDER BY  ASC ")
    SendKeys "^v"
End Sub
```

How can I do so efficiently as in the built-in double quotes command?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add some arrow keys right after `^v`:

```
Sub Main
    Clipboard(" ORDER BY  ASC ")
    SendKeys "^v^{LEFT}{LEFT}"
End Sub
```